# duplicates data after filtering and transfer it to another datagridview

Tags: vb.net, duplicates

i have 2 datagridview for filtering data the 1st datagridview is for the raw data and the 2nd datagridview is for the filtered data and i also have 1 button for filtering the data, once i click the button it filters the data and transfer the data to my 2nd datagridview, now my problem is when i encouter duplicates, it transfer to the 2nd datagridview but the data multiplies depending on how the many duplidates it filterd. example "3 duplicate data from 1st datagridview after clicking the button it multiplies by two so now in the 2nd datagrid i have 6 duplicates"

i tried some different code but i think the problem is the looping side

'''vb.net

```
 For Each row1 As DataGridViewRow In datagridview1.Rows
            For Each nextrow1 As DataGridViewRow In datagridview1.Rows
                If row1.Index <> nextrow1.Index Then
                    If row1.Cells(0).Value.ToString = 
   nextrow1.Cells(0).Value.ToString AndAlso row1.Cells(2).Value.ToString = 
   nextrow1.Cells(2).Value.ToString AndAlso row1.Cells(3).Value.ToString = 
   nextrow1.Cells(3).Value.ToString AndAlso row1.Cells(8).Value.ToString = 
   nextrow1.Cells(8).Value.ToString Then

                        datagridview2.Rows.Add(row1.Cells(0).Value, row1.Cells(1).Value, row1.Cells(2).Value, row1.Cells(3).Value, row1.Cells(4).Value, row1.Cells(5).Value, row1.Cells(6).Value, row1.Cells(7).Value, row1.Cells(8).Value, row1.Cells(9).Value, row1.Cells(10).Value, row1.Cells(11).Value, row1.Cells(12).Value, row1.Cells(13).Value, row1.Cells(14).Value, row1.Cells(15).Value, row1.Cells(16).Value, row1.Cells(17).Value)


                    End If
                End If

            Next

        Next '
```

what I want is when i click the button it will not multiply the duplicates from the 2nd datagrid

Comment: The issue is that you are comparing every row to every other row, which means that each pair of rows will be compared twice.  Instead of using `For Each` loops, use `For` loops and then you can ensure that the inner loop will only get rows after the one from the outer loop.

Comment: How is the first data grid filled?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `.DefaultView.ToTable` is distinct as Boolean.

```
    Private Sub LoadGrid()
    'I would expect that your DataTable would be loaded from a database
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(2) {New DataColumn("Id"), New DataColumn("Name"), New DataColumn("Country")})
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia")
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India")
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States")
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia")
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India")
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France")
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States")
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France")
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France")
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia")
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim dt As DataTable = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
    Dim ColumnNames() As String = {"Id", "Name", "Country"}
    dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(True, ColumnNames)
    DataGridView2.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Shamelessly stolen from https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Remove-Delete-Duplicate-Rows-Records-from-DataTable-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx